# Counting the number of brackets in a file

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that scans through a text file and counts the number of open and closed brackets for comparison. However so far ive only managed to count the first occurrence of a bracket in a line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fileName;
  fileName = fopen("/home/vagrant/Desktop/tests/t5", "r");

  if (fileName != NULL)
  {
    int noOfOpenPar=0;
    int noOfClosePar=0;
    int noOfOpenSqr=0;
    int noOfCloseSqr=0;
    int noOfOpenCurl=0;
    int noOfCloseCurl=0;
    char lineOfText[80];

    while (fgets(lineOfText, 80, fileName) != NULL)
    {
      if (strstr(lineOfText, "(") != NULL)
      noOfOpenPar++;
      if (strstr(lineOfText, ")") != NULL)
      noOfClosePar++;
      if (strstr(lineOfText, "[") != NULL)
      noOfOpenSqr++;
      if (strstr(lineOfText, "]") != NULL)
      noOfCloseSqr++;
      if (strstr(lineOfText, "{") != NULL)
      noOfOpenCurl++;
      if (strstr(lineOfText, "}") != NULL)
      noOfCloseCurl++;
    }
    printf ("\nThe number of open parenthesies is %d and closed parenthesies     %d\n", noOfOpenPar, noOfClosePar);
    if (noOfOpenPar!=noOfClosePar)
    printf("Number of open and closed parenthesies doesn't match\n");
    printf ("\nThe number of open square brackets is %d and closed square brackets is %d\n", noOfOpenSqr, noOfCloseSqr);
    if (noOfOpenSqr!=noOfCloseSqr)
    printf("Number of open and closed square brackets doesn't match\n");
    printf ("\nThe number of open curly brackets is %d and closed curly brackets is %d\n", noOfOpenCurl, noOfCloseCurl);
    if (noOfOpenCurl!=noOfCloseCurl)
    printf("Number of open and closed curly brackets doesn't match\n");

  }

}
```

Comment: You need more loops. Or to read the file character by character.

Comment: You do not know whether it matches just by counting. E.g `)(`, `([)]`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `strstr()` for this, it's better to simply iterate over all the characters and inspect them. You are looking for 1-character tokens, after all.

Something like this instead inside the loop:

```
for(const char *src = lineOfText; *src != '\0'; ++src)
{
  const char here = *src;
  if(here == '(')
    ++noOfOpenPar;
  else if(here == ')')
    ++noOfClosePar;
  else if ... /* more code here */
}
```

You get the idea. You *could* also rely on stdio's file buffering and just read a single character at a time, which would cut down on the number of loops, but I think this approach is better.

It could also of course be made more data-driven, by iterating through an array of structures holding characters to look for and their associated counters.

Comment: i'm getting "comparison between pointer and integer" errors at (src == '(')

Comment: `if(*src == '(')`

Comment: @WeatherVane D'oh, actually I meant to use `here`. Fixed, and thanks.